# Replace a variable in JSON with an item from a list

Tags: python, json

I am trying to replace a static variable in a JSON File with one from a list of text strings.

Here's an example of the JSON:

```
 {
  "ignorecase": true, 
  "parameter": "PARA", 
  "type": "querystring"
 }, 
 {
  "ignorecase": true, 
  "parameter": "PARA", 
  "type": "querystring"
 }, 
 {
  "ignorecase": true, 
  "parameter": "PARA", 
  "type": "querystring"
 }
```

In the JSON file, I need to replace PARA with an item from a list like `[cd, pid, pod]`

And I'm looking for an output like:

```
 {
  "ignorecase": true, 
  "parameter": "cd", 
  "type": "querystring"
 }, 
 {
  "ignorecase": true, 
  "parameter": "pid", 
  "type": "querystring"
 }, 
 {
  "ignorecase": true, 
  "parameter": "pod", 
  "type": "querystring"
 }
```

I think it should be really easy to do in Python but I'm struggling a bit. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import re
def repl(matchobj):
     return str(y.pop(0))
x='''  {
    "ignorecase": true, 
    "parameter": "PARA", 
    "type": "querystring"
  }, 
  {
    "ignorecase": true, 
    "parameter": "PARA", 
    "type": "querystring"
  }, 
  {
    "ignorecase": true, 
    "parameter": "PARA", 
    "type": "querystring"
  }'''
y=['cd', 'pid', 'pod']
print re.sub(r"PARA",repl,x)
```

The Error I get is `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Hoping to find a better way to set this up and be able to parse the JSON and easily replace. Thanks!

Comment: your code is working for me

Comment: i run your code and it is running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the json standard library. Turn your json into a dictionary, modify it, and serialize it back to json. The functions you're interested in are `dumps` for Dump-String, which converts native python data structures to json strings and `loads`, for Load-String, which is the inverse.

For instance

```
import json
data = json.loads(x)
y = ['cd', 'pid', 'pod']
for obj in data:
    if obj['parameter'] == 'PARA':
        obj['parameter'] = y.pop()

json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard library [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) that I think will do what you are wanting.

Specifically you are going to want to read it in using `json.loads(x)` and after modifying it you will do `json.dumps(modified_x)`